# I can't format Python file on Visual Studio Code: "There is no document formatter for 'python'-files installed."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this message

> *There is no document formatter for 'python'-files installed.*

When I try to format a `Python` file on `Visual Studio Code`.

I tried to install some packages (`autopep8`, `pep8`, `pycodestyle`), but they didn't help. What's going on?

Comment: more recently, see [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](/q/77283648/11107541)

Answer (score 5):

More than likely you installed `autopep8` into a different interpreter/environment than you one have selected in VS Code. If you remove your formatter settings from your `settings.json` and then try formatting again, you will get prompted to choose and install a formatter (either `autopep8`, `yapf`, or `black`).

Comment: Installing the `autopep8` extension fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I was using Prettier. Thus it doesn't support python properly or vscode doesn't recognize it as python formatter.
I installed autopep8 for python in extentions bar. Then I configured the `settings.json` for user and workspace `settings.json`:

user settings:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    
},
```

workspace-settings:

```
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings": {
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path_to_your_project",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    }
},
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for similar extensions that you've installed. Uninstall unnecessary extensions and check in your settings for mutually exclusive settings. I had for example:

```
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
```

and

```
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

which was making my auto formatting  not functioning.